# How can I send a request to the API using form-data type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a request to the API. I need to submit the request using form-data type. After the response, it throws the exception.

The exception message is as follows: The format of the value '{"Id":"1111111","Message":"something","Description":"something"}' is invalid.

```
 SendingRequestModel requestModel = new SendingRequestModel();

 requestModel.Id = "1111111";
 requestModel.Message = "something";
 requestModel.Description= "something";

 string message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestModel);

 var serviceSettings = appSettings.ServiceSettings;

 var options = new RestClientOptions(serviceSettings.ServiceUrl)
 {
     Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password")
 };
 var client =
     new RestClient(options);

 var request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.Post, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.RequestBody);

 using (MultipartFormDataContent formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
 {
     KeyValuePair<string, string>[] keyValuePairs = new[]
     {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message", message),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("queue-name", "notification")
     };
     foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
     {
         request.AddParameter(keyValuePair.Value, keyValuePair.Key);
     }
 }

 var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

[image]

Comment: how is the api defined? have you found an api definition file like open api?

Comment: @CelalSunnetci `request` has a data type of JSON, so that's why you are getting the invalid response. You need to use multip-part form data, currently you have a `using` but never actually do anything with the `MultiPartFormDataContent`, [send-form-data-in-c-sharp-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848923/send-form-data-in-c-sharp-httpclient)

Comment: @Charlieface You're right. But I think they want to be using `MultiPartFormDataContent` object?

Comment: @RyanWilson If there is another way I can do that too

Comment: @CelalSunnetci You should be able to set the content of your `HttpRequest` to the `MultipartFormDataContent `

Comment: I'm afraid that you'd better to call this api successfully via postman first, then I think it should be easy to offer you a code sample about how to send this request in your .net core project.

Comment: here's a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67396396/14574199) for submitting form in asp.net core. by the way, if we are trying for submit a form, the value must be string, if you are trying to submit a json object in the value, you need to convert it to string in advance.